# Apache Pig Java UDF - import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc; cannot be resolved

Tags: apache-pig

*Eclipse is showing the error message `import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc; cannot be resolved`.How can I get rid of this error ? Below is the POM file*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Pig</groupId>
  <artifactId>PigUDF</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  </build>
   </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add pig dependency to your POM file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.0</version><!-- or any version you want -->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

EvalFunc class is imported from Pig Packages. So You need to add the pig dependency in pom.xml.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pig/pig -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
    <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```